# What does the environment means in Ishikawa (fishbone) diagram

Tags: design, diagrams, engineering

I am designing an Information System for the French Social security system and would like advice on how to use Ishikawa (fishbone) diagrams to model said information system.

My question specifically is about the definition of "environment" in this diagram. What is the common definition for "environment" in such diagrams?

[image: Ishikawa (fishbone) diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Environment is any thing outside our system i.e., other than our people, process, machines. It can be political environment, government regulations, weather conditions etc.

However, Ishikawa diagram is only used for identifying potential causes of problems that resulted or may result into failure.

Comment: Okay, we used it to design a Information System...